# how to set the value of the "x" field, depending on the "y" field from another model? Odoo-10

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-10

I want to enter the value in field "y" from class "yCla", depending of value from field "x" from class "xCla"

```
class xCla(models.Model):
    . . .
    x = fields.Char()

class yCla(models.Model):
    #I did not inherit anything
    #this two models are from same module
    . . .
    y = fields.Char()
```

if I was not clear enough, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

If there is no relation between this two models `xCLa` and `yCla`, then the easiest way will be to implement the logic in `xCla` models `write` or `create` function. But if they are related for example there is relation between `yCla` and `xCla`, then this can be achieved by using `compute` or `related` functionality on field properties.

Comment: thank you for your answer, what do you mean by the relationship between the models, I tried to 'compute' , but odoo is raise error the field "x" does not exist

Comment: by relationship i meant relation field on 'xCla' which is to'yCla' record

Comment: in odoo really field between two models are fields.Many2one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice @arryph , I added this in my code and now I work as I wanted

```
class xCla(models.Model):
    _name = 'x_name'
    . . .
    x = fields.Char()

class yCla(models.Model):
    _name = 'y_name'
    . . .
    abc = fields.Many2one('x_name')
    y = fields.Char()

    @api.onchange('abc')
    def _onchange_abc_x(self):
        self.y = self.abc.x
```

If someone knows a easy way, please let write in the answers :)

Comment: Actually you don't need @api.onchange. Just use related property on `y`
Just remove the onchange function and edit `y` field as following
`y = fields.Char(related='abc.x', store=True)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried, this works on most modules, but name of modul in my code is actualy '_name = some.thing' (with dot '.' in midle of name) so when I start Odoo-10 it's rise error not possible to find the module "some"
In any case thank you very much this is very useful :)

Comment: all of the Odoo core modules are named like that, it shouldn't be any issue. For example `ir.base, stock.picking` etc etc.